# Unable to edit panels in Mint 19.1 (Tessa)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, cinnamon, panel

I have recently upgraded from Mint 18.3 to 19.1 Cinnamon, by a two-stage process. I had to install 19.0 first.

Since upgrading, I cannot edit panels. The following commands on the panel context menu do not work (i.e. a click achieves nothing, no action, no error message, nothing at all):

```
• Add applets to the panel
• Panel settings
• Themes
• System settings
```

It is the same regardless of the Panel edit mode.

I have similar problems with the desktop context menu. I cannot change the background or add Desklets, but I can create a launcher. Also, the screensaver does not work.

The problems have persisted over reboots and Cinnamon restarts.

During the upgrade, I deleted lots of packages, due to having accumulated much rubbish, as I tried different desktop environments and other packages. I thought it was safe as I was upgrading anyway.

Of course, I can do a fresh install, but I would prefer to avoid that, as I have other stuff that is working well.

Am I missing any Cinnamon components? Is there a ‘repair’ option available?

Answer (score 0):

Icons are moved individually. Right click on an icon. uncheck 'Lock to Panel'
Right click on icon again 'Move'

E :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I have overcome these problems (and others) with a clean install.